# Finding out how change in other variables influence change in target variable

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, polynomial

I have data in form of time series that consist 2 variables for 3 different products. First variable is quantity sold and the second is price for each month. And that is repeated for every product.
So the data will look like this

```
        P1_price P1_quantity P2_price P2_quantity P3_price P3_quantity
2019-1-1  20          590       19        400     10         1500
2019-1-2  20.5        580       19.7      41     10         1521
```

What I want to find out is how changes in price in P1 P2 P3 affect quantity sold of each product resepctively.
So what I did was use linear regression, where P1_quantity is target and P1_Price, P2_price P3_price are independent variables.

However using linear model did not take into account how the quantity sold would change from different price points, i.e. change of 1 US dollar from 20 usd price should not have the same effect like from 25 usd price as the linear model implies.

So I added quadratic terms into the function. But I'm not sure if this is correct approach to this problem. Is that a good way to deal with this issue?

In both cases, linear and quadratic the models were good fit (R2 around 0.95)

Comment: You need to elaborate as to why you think it shouldn't be doing that, what you would like it to do and why.

Comment: I dont meant it should not be doing that, I just wonder what is correct approach for this kind of data?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by `change of 1 US dollar from 20 usd price should not have the same effect like from 25 usd price as the linear model implies`?